# Fetching date in different formats from string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex

below is the text from which i want to fetch the dates in different format.

> "Sales Assistant @ DFS Duration - **June 2021 - 2023** Currently working
> in XYZ Within the role I am expected to achieve sales targets which I
> currently have no problems reaching. Job Role/Establishment -
> Plasterer @ XX Plasterer’s Duration - **September 2016 - Nov 2016** A Job
> Role/Establishment - Customer Advisor @ AA Duration - **(2015 – 2016)**
> Job Role/Establishment - Warehouse Operative @ xyz Duration - **03/2014
> to 08/2015** In the xyz warehouse Job Role/Establishment - Airport
> Terminal Assistant @ port Duration - **01/2012 - 06/2013** Working at the
> airport . Job Role/Establishment - Apprentice Floorer @ YY Floors
> Duration - **DEC 2010 to APRIL 2012**a"   **(12/03/2020)-(2/11/2021)** Fetch
> dates with different formats @TEST Duration - **(December- March2022)**
> and thsi is test @BLA Duration - **(July-December 2019)** - This is test
> trying to fetch dates with diff formats  -  **05/22 - 2023**. @
> Plasterer's Duration - **10/21 - 05/22**   16-17 other starts from **31
> september 2022 to 01 january 2023** towards ends it starts from **july
> 2022 - january 2023** .

This is the regex logic [check here to see regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/1523VU/1)  that matches with the majority of date format but still misses the date in  **31 september 2022 to 01 january 2023** this format. Also current pattern fetches 16-17 which is not required

```
\(?(?:\b[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*)?(?:\d\d?\/){0,2}[12]\d(?:\d{2})?\)?\s*(?:–|-|[Tt][Oo])\s*\(?(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*)?(?:\d\d?\/){0,2}[12]\d(?:\d{2})?\)?|\(\s*[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*[--]\s*[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*[12]\d{3}\s*\)
```

what changes needs to be made.? any leads.? or any other efficient way to fetch the same..?

Comment: how will you match the pattern for `July-December 2019` and `Duration - June 2021`? as you can see both are almost same pattern. if you want to avoid the mismatches you have to add the exact month in regex

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/RI6xCk/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the alternatives more specific and use a case insensitive match:

```
\(\d\d?/\d\d?/\d{4}\)\s*[-–]\s*\(\d\d?/\d\d?/\d{4}\)|\((?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}|\d{4})\s*[-–]\s*(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9})?\s*\d{4}\)|\b\d\d?\s+[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*[-–]\s*\d{4}\s+to\s+\d\d?\s+[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s+\d{4}\b|\b[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s+\d{4}\s*(?:[-–]|to)(?:\s*[A-Za-z]{3,9})?\s+\d{4}|\b\d\d?/(?:\d{4}|\d\d?)\s+(?:to|[-–])\s+(?:\d\d?/)?(?:\d{4}|\d\d?)\b
```

It is a long pattern, but these are the 5 alternatives with a description.

- `\(\d\d?/\d\d?/\d{4}\)\s*[-–]\s*\(\d\d?/\d\d?/\d{4}\)` Match `(...)-(...)` with digits and `/` as separator
- `|` Or
- `\((?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}|\d{4})\s*[-–]\s*(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9})?\s*\d{4}\)` Match `(...)-(...)` with leading chars a-z or 4 digits, then `-` followed by optional chars a-z and then 4 digits
- `|` Or
- `\b\d\d?\s+[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*[-–]\s*\d{4}\s+to\s+\d\d?\s+[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s+\d{4}\b` Match digits and chars a-z with `-` and `to`
- `|` Or
- `\b[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s+\d{4}\s*(?:[-–]|to)(?:\s*[A-Za-z]{3,9})?\s+\d{4}` Match  chars a-z with 4 digits, `to` or `-` and optional chars followed by 4 digits
- `|` Or
- `\b\d\d?/(?:\d{4}|\d\d?)\s+(?:to|[-–])\s+(?:\d\d?/)?(?:\d{4}|\d\d?)\b` Match 1 or 2 digits followed by `/` and 1,2 or 4 digits. Then match `to` or `-` and again 1-2 digits `/` and 1,2 or 4 digits

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lhLlfl/1).

Comment: kudos..!! but its not detecting 2014-2015 such format i.e. without parenthesis. what changes needs to be made  https://regex101.com/r/HgAMX9/1

Comment: @Romi As we already have a list with alternatives: https://regex101.com/r/0R5okA/1